Ubuntu can't see shared folders. Only sees Print$
I have a Ubuntu setup on a macmini acting as a file server. I have set up my smb.conf to share my folders.
I can see the folders when I access them from my Win10 machine and iphone (using Filebrowser) just fine.
However, using another Ubuntu box I see that the MacMini comes up under networks.  I click on it and all I see is a Print$ folder and not any of my shared folders.
I use "connect to server" and enter "smb://myserver" I also get just the Print$ folder.  But if I enter a specified folder directly like "smb://myserver/myfolder" and then enter in the user and password at least the folder and contents are displayed and accessible.
Is this a configuration problem on Ubuntu?  I'm not sure why the shares are displayed properly on Windows and my iphone.
Thoughts?

Why not post the output of the following command so the folks here can see how you are set up: testparm -s
